# How to fix: dpkg: Warning: Files list file for package nodejs-doc missing?

Tags: apt, dpkg, nodejs

So i completely removed Nodejs by running file manager as Root and deleting every search hit for "nodejs".
'
After i installed NodeJs again i get the following warning everytime:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nodejs-doc' missing; assuming package has no files
 currently installed
(Reading database ... 228170 files and directories currently installed.)
```

How do i get the nodejs-doc files list back?

Comment: You shouldn’t have deleted node manually. You’ve possibly deleted data stored in apt’s cache.

Comment: So what now? What should I do?

Comment: Not my expertise, but I’d try clearing your apt cache first. Try `sudo apt purge 'nodejs*' && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs`

Comment: @galexite thanks, i will try this! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to user @galexite i fixed it with

```
 sudo apt purge 'nodejs*' && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: Glad it worked!